# Is "plantingly" an adverb?

Tags: idioms, adverbs, analogy

Is *plantingly* an adverb form of *plant*? Can you give me a example sentence?

Edit: This use of *plantingly* came from the following quote:

> Firstly I [would like] to thank you for taking the time from your [busy] schedule to help we **plantingly challenged**.

Comment: Did you see this word somewhere?  If so, please give the sentence you saw.  Or, if you wish to use this word, can you explain what you expect it to mean?

Comment: I saw it here:: http://en.allexperts.com/q/Landscaping-Design-724/Emerald-Green-Bare-Spots.htm

Comment: That *we* in the quote should probably be *us*.

Comment: I would add, several months later, that the writer of that sentence is not very good at writing. "Firstly I wouldl ike to thankyou for taking the time from your bust schedule to help we plantingly challanged Thanks." One might say he was grammatically challenged, among other things.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On its own, the word *plantingly* is not a "real" word (not much evidence of use, not in dictionary).  However, in this particular sentence, *plantingly* is being used in the phrase "plantingly challenged".  This is a phrase that was formed by analogy with other phrases of the form "**_**_ly challenged", for example:

- mentally challenged (mental difficulties)
- academically challenged (academic difficulties)
- financially challenged (financial difficulties)
- socially challenged (social difficulties)
- etc.

In the case of "plantingly challenged", the phrase is supposed to mean that the person has difficulty with planting.  The *-ly* suffix was added to this word in order to maintain the form of other "**__**_ly challenged" phrases (and in this case, the use is intended to be playful or humorous).

Comment: You forgot "vertically challenged" :)